# Obtener el mes de una fecha que es ingresada mediante un String en formato dd/mm/yy

Tags: java

Deseo solo obtener el mes de una fecha la cual es ingresada por un usuario y esta entra como un String o sea: 22/09/2019 ó 19, para este caso no tiene importancia.

Por ejemplo:

```
String fecha = "22/09/2019";
```

Necesito extraer el mes de alli, para luego hacer comparaciones, pero no hallo la forma de extraer el mes de alli.

Answer (score -1):

Usas la clase **StringTokenizer** donde el separador para tu caso es "/" (diagonal), en base a lo que dices sabemos que el segundo valor es el mes, es decir, dd/mm/yy o dd/mm/yyyy, en ambos casos el mes es el segundo **token**.

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String fecha = "22/09/2019";
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(fecha, "/");
        st.nextToken(); // obtener primer token

        String mes = st.nextToken(); // obtener segundo token
        // No hace falta obtener el 3er token

        System.out.println("MES en String: " + mes);
        System.out.println("MES en int: " + Integer.valueOf(mes) );

    }
}
```

**Salida:**

```
MES en String: 09
MES en int: 9
```

Mas información de la clase **StringTokenizer**: https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_en_Java/La_clase_StringTokenizer

Comment: Otra pregunta, me podrias explicar mejor esto de los tokens? , muchas gracias ya cumpli con extraer el mes, ¿Hay manera de extraerlo de alli sin importar nada? 

Gracias :)

Comment: Se dice token al String que está dividido por el simbolo que elijas.
22/09/2019

Tiene 3 tokens porque se puede dividir usando el simbolo "/" (diagonal)
[1er token --> 22]   
[2do token --> 09]   
[3er token ---> 2019]  

No importa el largo del String que vayas a dividir, los tokens se determinan por el simbolo que los separa.